# How to filter a SQL view to this month only

Tags: sql, filter

Hi I'm new to this so be gentle with me, I have created a SQL view and need to filter this in sql before loading the data in excel, I want to filter the data to this month only.

So the SQL is

```
SELECT DocumentNo, DocumentDate, TotalNetValue, TotalTaxValue, TotalGrossValue
FROM dbo.SOPOrderReturn
```

And that returns this

[image: Table]

Comment: your used dbms name please

Comment: First, please don't post images, post the data as table-formatted text. Second, please tag your DBMS. Date functions vary wildly between DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly encourage you to use a version that can use an index:

```
SELECT DocumentNo, DocumentDate, TotalNetValue, TotalTaxValue, TotalGrossValue
FROM dbo.SOPOrderReturn
WHERE DocumentDate >= DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE(), -1)) AND
      DocumentDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(GETDATE());
```

Because no function is applied to `DocumentDate`, the optimizer would be able to use an index.

Note that `EOMONTH()` is available since SQL Server 2012.  There are equivalent methods in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use month function to get the month number and filter.

```
SELECT DocumentNo, DocumentDate, TotalNetValue, TotalTaxValue, TotalGrossValue
FROM dbo.SOPOrderReturn where month(DocumentDate)=9 and Year(DocumentDate)=2018
```

Comment: You also need the year else you'll that month for every year in the table.

Comment: You also need to generalize such that the month/year changes as the calendar changes. Your code is locked to September. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the month/year of the document to the current month/year.

```
SELECT DocumentNo, DocumentDate, TotalNetValue, TotalTaxValue, TotalGrossValue
FROM dbo.SOPOrderReturn
WHERE MONTH(DocumentDate) = MONTH(getdate())
AND YEAR(DocumentDate) = YEAR(getdate())
```